# Default splash screen is not getting rotated on ipad

Tags: ipad

I have two images in my app "Default-LandscapeLeft.png" and "Default-LandscapeRight.png". But during the app launch if I rotate my ipad then default image does not get rotated.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS will only use the orientation at application launch time - it won't swap default images. In most cases, the second of showing the splash screen at the wrong orientation is not an issue. If your application takes a very long time to start I would advise working on that.